# Prove that if $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y,\tau\prime)$ is a continuous function and $X$ is connected then the graph of $f$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

It is required to prove that if $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y,\tau\prime)$ is a continuous function and $X$ is connected then the graph of $f$ is connected. The following is my attempt.

Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is connected $f(X)$ is connected. The graph of $f$ is the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ which is precisely $X\times f(X)$. But $X\times f(X)$ is connected as the product of two connected spaces is connected. Hence the graph of $f$ is connected.

Is this proof alright?

Does the graph being connected imply that it can be drawn (if it can) without lifting the pencil until it's done? Thanks.

Comment: The graph of $f$ is not equal to the product, for instance take $f(x)=x$ to visualize

Comment: Got it. The product has more points than the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous function of topological space, then
its graph $\Gamma(f)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:f(x)=y\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$.
So if $X$ is connected or Hausdorff or compact or whatever, then so is $\Gamma(f)$.

Connectedness no longer has anything to do with pencils.

Comment: "Connectedness no longer has anything to do with pencils."  :)

Comment: My questions was whether **the graph can be drawn** without lifting the pencil if **it is connected**.

Answer (score 0):

The map $1_X \nabla f : X \to X \times Y$ where $1_X \nabla f(x) = (x, f(x))$ is continuous as $p_X \circ (1_X \nabla f) = 1_X$, the identity on $X$, which is continuous, and $p_Y \circ (1_X \nabla f) = f$, also continuous. As a map into a product is continuous iff the composition with the projections are all continuous, $1_X \nabla f$ is continuous and so $\Gamma(f) = (1_X \nabla f)[X]$ is connected whenever $X$ is.
Even: $1_X \nabla f$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $\Gamma(f)$, with continuous inverse $\pi_X | \Gamma(f)$

So $X$ is connected iff $\Gamma(f)$ is connected.